# How to respond to a client request from a servlet without reseting the controls in jsp form

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am a building project in which I am using java-beans,jsp and servlets. I need to send the response to the client on the same page from where request was made with a slightly modified html. But when I(server) sent the request to the jsp page, the controls in the form are getting reset to their original value. But I don't want to override the user's input after the request was made. One way to achieve this is to take value of the property for each control in the form when request is made and then set them again while responding. Actually there are a large number of controls in my form, taking values of each doesn't seem efficient.

So is there some other way to keep the form in the jsp file unchanged while responding to the client.

Comment: This method is called *AJAX*, you could do it adding jQuery to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use iframe ? so you dont have to refresh the whole page when the request is made to the same page.

Instead of making the action of the form to the same page, call a javascript function that set the parameters in the link and then

```
var f = document.getElementById('iframe');
f.src = 'newlink';
f.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

This populated the iframe with the latest content

Comment: How do we do that with iframe?

Comment: even in the case of iframe you will need to refresh the page thus you need to use the ajax call , thus you get the dynamic data without refreshing the page , and then you can refresh your iframe or any div content you want

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid :
Ajax call while submitting the form or from the servlets while responding to the client.??

Comment: @Manish : see that depends on your requirement , call the ajax function whenever you want to reload the particular part of your view page

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid :
Ok..I don't have any idea about Ajax as I haven't used it till now. So I think if this is the only way to achieve this I need to learn Ajax first..Anyway thanks to all for ur responses.

Comment: exactly now just call this function or the ajax call whichever you want , call this function when just when you think the content of the iframe should be reloaded

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax for what you are asking, or you have to save the data on form submit, in session or some place and set them back again while responding. Apart from that I think there is no other way you can retain form data even after page reload.

Thanks 
Chakri

Answer (score 0):

```
function openOffenderInfo(i)
{
  $.ajax({
          url:'../loginServlet',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) 
     {
        alert("reset your div values in this block");
            .... for example .....
            documnet.getElementById('reloading Div').innerHTML=data;
     },
    error: function(data) 
    {
       alert("error");
    }
    });
}
```

URL : c=name of the servlet you want to call
this servlet calculates the data and gives the new data you want to reset in your div

success : this is the function which will be executes if your ajax call is made successfully
so you can set the values of your reloading part inside this function

I hope this might serve you the purpose

Comment: The data parameter in the success function is the data which servlet forwarded or something else?

Comment: yeah the data in the success function is the data returned by the servlet

Comment: @Manish : make sure jquery is working fine , and if u need anything else , let me know